# What is the meaning of the 「だろうが」 in 「仲間だろうが！！！！」

Tags: particle-が

It is from a line in *One Piece*:

[image]

Another instance from the same manga:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://yeemar.seesaa.net/article/14242770.html), 三省堂国語辞典 says:

> 「だろうが」「でしょうが」などの形で文末につき、「念をおして相手をなっとくさせようとする気持ちをあらわす」（『三省堂国語辞典』）

And [デジタル大辞泉's entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/34931/m0u/) says:

> [３]［終助］
>   ２ （多く体言や体言の下にののしる意の接尾語「め」を伴ったものに付いて）ののしりの感情を強める。「このあほうめ―」「あいつめ―」「敵(かたき)の回し者め―」〈伎・幼稚子敵討〉

I think those pictures show its usage better than a hundred words. This が was used because they were upset, and they tried to strongly convince people in front of them.

> - 言ったでしょう？　I told you, didn't I? (already accusatory)
> - 言ったでしょうが！ (even stronger)