# Could someone please check if this translation is accurate?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate these two sentences:

> Question: "D-BOYSで仲良いのはやっぱり、あらやんですか？"
>   Answer: "ベタだけどやっぱり仲間が1番しっくりくるかな。"

Is it OK to translate them like this?

> Q: Among the D-BOYS, the person closer to you is Arayan, after all?
>   A: It's a cliché but I guess all my friends are the best match for me.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you very much!!

Comment: "Best match" sounds a lot more like a romantic dating situation.  To say that one's 仲間 are しっくりくる-ing, a more natural English expression might be to say that they are _close_ with their friends, or in a slangier tone, one is _tight_ with their friends.

Answer (score 1):

> ベタだけどやっぱり仲間が1番しっくりくるかな。

- This ベタだ implies "(What I am saying from now is) unsurprising / uninteresting". He said this because he felt his answer might be disappointing to the interviewer and his fans.
- 仲間がしっくりくる in this context (probably) means "I'm (most) comfortable if I call him a 仲間" or "the most fitting word to describe Arayan is 仲間".

So, instead of directly saying "Yes" or "No", I think he said the relationship with Arayan is best described as [仲間 rather than 友達](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22957/5010). That is, he euphemistically denied Arayan is his personal [仲良し](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%B2%E8%89%AF%E3%81%97).

(I said *probably* because his reply might be interpreted in a different way depending on the following sentence. Is that all he said as the ansewr?)