# Appropriate word for "fellow"

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

I've been wondering how to appropriately say the phrase "My fellow members" lately and I've come up with the phrase 「僕の仲間のメンバーたち」but I feel like there's a more appropriate word for it.

Is there a more appropriate word for "fellow" than 「仲間」?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English *fellow* has multiple meanings and it's impossible to give a catch-all term. For reference, here's [what ALC says](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=fellow&ref=sa):

> 1. **男**、**男の子**、**やつ**
> 2. 〈話〉**ボーイフレンド**、**男友達**◆【用法】やや古めかしい表現。
> 3. **同輩**、**同期生**◆経歴や地位などが同じ人。
> 4. **仲間**、**同志**◆【用法】やや古めかしい表現。
> 5. 〔二つのうちの〕**片方**、**片割れ**
> 6. 〔学会や職能団体の〕**会員**
> 7. 〔大学や研究所の〕**特別研究員**、**フェロー**
> 8. 〈英〉〔オックスフォード大学などの〕**評議員**

---

You can use 同僚 when it's close to "colleague", 同期(生) when the sameness of social status or generation is important, 同級生 for [this sense](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52315/5010), and 仲間 for [this sense](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22957/5010). If it refers to teammates of an in-company sport team, 仲間 or チームメイト should work. When in doubt, you can always say 同じチームの人, 同じ会社の人 or such. 仲間のメンバー is awkward because it sounds like "fellows who are also members (of another group)" or "members of (a group called) *Nakama*".

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the context.
It's hard to answer your question without knowing what kind of group your fellow members belong to.
One thing I can say now is that 僕の仲間のメンバーたち is a quite awkward phrase because 仲間 and メンバー share a similar meaning.

Comment: For a specific context, I'm talking about members of a team within a company. However I'm also looking for words that fit outside that context, such as "fellow students" or "fellow players", generally something used to address other people in the same group as oneself.