# How to say 'fellow sweet tooth'

Tags: word-choice

How do I say 'fellow sweet tooth' (noun) in japanese. I'd thought it would be either 甘党仲間 or 甘党同僚 but there's probably something more accurate

Comment: In what context (e.g. sentence) are you planning to use it? I'm asking this because noun usage referring to people could be intricate in Japanese.

Comment: @broccoliforest Sentence: As a fellow sweet tooth, lets go to a cake buffet. I'd thought of 同甘党, but not sure if such a word exists

Comment: Very very helpful context. That's why I needed it before I'd write a pointless answer.

Answer (score 3):

The word "fellow" in English is often [too casually used to find an all-around translation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64767/7810).

Moreover, in the provided context:

> *As a fellow sweet tooth, let's go to a cake buffet.*

this *fellow* practically stands for "me, who am one of" and probably "me, like you guys". In this case, I don't think any literal-ish translation of "fellow" works.

Natural ways to express it would be:

> 甘党の一人として、ケーキ食べ放題に行きたい［です］
>   （同じ）甘党どうし、ケーキ食べ放題に行［かない／きませんか］？
>   甘党のみんな、ケーキ食べ放題に行［こう／きましょう］
>   [plain/polite]

甘党仲間 sounds somewhat not right in this context, because it's like talking about the third party, or from a distant view point.
同僚 is unusable at all, as it only means "colleague".

Answer (score 0):

For calling out purpose, how about "甘党諸君?" When you want to just refer them, "甘党仲間" should be fine.