# What's the use of がよ in 「ダサ坊がよ」

Tags: meaning, particles

For clarity:
Two delinquent gangs were fighting but one of them was way weaker than the other. After getting beaten up the strong gang says:

> 気合いも何もねえ　ダサ坊がよ

1. What's がよ?
2. What about 気合いもなにも? What does it mean? I would translate it as "You don't have fighting spirit or anything. You're lame brats."

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62545/9831 (「～も何も(ない)」) Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18600/9831

Comment: as for がよ, it is the same one used in [What is the meaning of the 「だろうが」 in 「仲間だろうが！！！！」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21515/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-%e3%81%a0%e3%82%8d%e3%81%86%e3%81%8c-in-%e4%bb%b2%e9%96%93%e3%81%a0%e3%82%8d%e3%81%86%e3%81%8c)

Comment: @JimmyYang No, I think this が is a vocative particle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What's がよ?

If you're sure that this が is not a subject marker, then this が should be a derogatory vocative particle (see: [Why is が added at the end of この小娘が?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60514/5010)) and よ is a sentence-end particle. So Xがよ is like "Damn you, X" or something.

> 2. What about 気合いもなにも?

～も何もない is a set phrase. See:

- [How to understand い adjective + ある？ What is ある doing here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64794/5010)
- [Meaning of もクソも in 何かもクソも寝るだけだよ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76339/5010)

So the basic meaning is "this is not a matter of 気合い". Perhaps this guy wanted to say "You're way too weak physically, and just having a fighting spirit means nothing"?

**EDIT:** On second thought, I noticed this 気合も何もねえ could be a simple relative clause that modifies ダサ坊 (i.e., "You lame brat who doesn't even have a fighting spirit!"). See the context.